# How can I make a program generate a random number with a set pattern to follow in c# with .net framework?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am familiar with generating random numbers, but this would be more like a code I guess. What I want it to do is follow a specified pattern and generate numbers for every x in the code while there are some set numbers. The code pattern would be something like this: xx0xxxx00xx0. I want the program to make the x's into something random, but keep the zero's. If you have any questions or any way I could make my question better, feel free to comment! Also if this is a duplicate question, just tell me and I can remove it. Thanks!

Comment: For each group of Xs generate a random number and then concatenate the random numbers with 0’s between?

Comment: @Justas Why didnt I think of that! Thank you!

Comment: Remember that random numbers are not unique. Are you expecting the same “code pattern” to be generated multiple times? Because it will be.

Comment: Rather than doing string concatenation, use addition and multiplication (for example, for the right-most pair of Xes, generate a number between 0 and 99 then multiply by 10. Once you get all your x-sets generated, add them up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using regex. A simple example to get you started would be:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var code = "xx0xxxx00xx0";

        var numStr = Regex.Replace(code, @"([^0-9.])", x => new Random().Next(1,9).ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(numStr);
    }

    // 450871700340
```

With this approach, you could really give it any sort of code with that
x0 format you are using.

Comment: if you want the string to be a number, given your example "code", it will need to be a long type due to its size. You would use long.Parse(numStr)